# What approach is being used to create this animated text effect?

Tags: javascript, animation, jquery-plugins

Hope this is in the correct place to ask this question

I've been tasked with recreating the animated text effect on the headings on this page https://studioakademi.com/ On scrolling, the letters in words switch from a glyph style font to the actual font. I've viewed the source code but can't see any clues as to what's making this happen. Can anybody throw some light on it? Or suggest an approach that will do something close to it? I've not been able to find anything from my searching so far.

Any advice greatly appreciated. 
Cheers 
Grant

Comment: you can use "builtWith" chrome extension to understand which frameworks and technologies used in a website. https://builtwith.com

Comment: oh I guess I missunderstood your question, my bad

Answer (score 1):

take a look at html first:
before you scroll down, the html element containing text looks like this, pay attention to class:

```
<h1 class="intro-text-fadeout">
            Design studio<br>
            with digital<br>
            focus.
</h1>
```

After you scroll down this changes into:

```
<h1 class="intro-text-fadeout faded">
            Design studio<br>
            with digital<br>
            focus.
 </h1>
```

and then take a look at css:

```
section.frontpage-intro-text h1.intro-text-fadeout {
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```

and for faded:

```
section.frontpage-intro-text h1.intro-text-fadeout.faded {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

so basically when you add class `faded` to `h1` element it fades out in `400ms` to 0 opacity, it can be done easily in jquery, proof of concept:

```
$('h1.intro-text-fadeout').scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop > 100){
        $(this).addClass('faded');
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass('faded');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention to this Stetoc, I really appreciate it! But I should have been clearer, I meant the funky animated effect that comes after that, a bit lower down, that seems to randomly switch out letters in the word.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function randomtext() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}
```

Get a random character using the above function then use `setInterval` to randomly change the text in the header and after the interval update the text to what it's supposed to be. This will give you an effect similar to the one on the website.

**Update:**

```
<span id='text_to_change'>sometext</span>
```

Say you have a `<span>` tag with id `text_to_change` and some text. You access it in JavaScript like this.

```
var text = document.getElementById("text_to_change").value
```

Now we have text with a string with value 'sometext'
Get the length of the string using `text.length`

Check the example below to get an idea on how it works, play around with the code to get the required output. Hope it Helps!

#### Example

```js
function randomtext() 
{
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}

function replaceAt(string, index, replace) {
  return string.substring(0, index) + replace + string.substring(index + 1);
}

var text_val = "sometext"
var final_text = "IamChangedText"

function callback(i)
{

  var j = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 5);
  var test = setInterval(function(){
    j--;
    if(i < final_text.length)
    {
      text_val=replaceAt(text_val,i,randomtext()) 
    }
        if(j>1)
        {
        clearInterval(test);
        if(i < final_text.length)
        {

         text_val =replaceAt(text_val,i,final_text.charAt(i))
         console.log(text_val)
         callback(i+1);

        }
        }

  },50);
}
console.log(text_val)
callback(0)
```

Comment: Thanks Faik Malik, I'm not sure that I understand all that you've got here, but I'll see how I get on with it. I may need some more help with that. Thanks for your attention to this problem.

Comment: Hi Faik, function randomtext() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}

Comment: Hi Faik, Sorry, that first one got away from me. I don't understand javascript well enough to make sense of what you've told me. Could you explain it a bit more please?

Comment: Wow! Thanks Faik, a very detailed answer. I'll study what you've done there. Thanks again.

Comment: Great that it helped, please select it as solution then.